# How to upload a website into github

Tags: github

i downloaded a template which is know as "Start Bootstrap - Agency" and i edited, but when i try to upload the edited version in to github it picks the old version (before edition). Please can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you staged and committed your new build, or does `git status` say you still have unsaved changes?

Answer (score 0):

Git has the concept of commit and push along with branches. 
You have to stage/add your changes for commit, commit the changes to a specific branch and then push them to a upstream like Github.

You can read more here

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/